# Denodo Join between disparate sources without cache

Tags: data-virtualization, denodo

I am new to Denodo, just have installed Denodo Express Server.I am running a sample task.

I have two disparate data sources (Postgres and MySQL), Postgres has *agents* table while MySQL has *Customer* and *Orders* data. When I execute a join statement between *agents* and *Customer* data it return 0 rows, until I cache *Customer* data.

1. Is there any way we can execute join statement between different sources without Caching, as It results replication cost?

I have attached the Execution Trace of the query, both Virtual Plans return some rows but Inner Join Plan results 0 rows.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your join condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are joining **TEXT** field. May be in your text field there is space before and after field or In-between tow word.

You can use `trim()` for both side before joining OR Try to remove all space from your string and Join.

I am just Guessing because you didn't provide join condition.

Comment: Thanks Nirav for the response. It was some dependency issue, and has resolved by one of Denodo Engg.